# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined | When i try to import a component with babel-dynamic-import

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, react-loadable, dynamic-import

I am trying to import a react component with `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` but i can not make it work.

Here is my code in my main componant :

```
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const Test = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./Space').default,
  loading: <div>loading</div>
});

const App = () => <Test />;
export default App;
```

And my code in my Space component :

```
import React from 'react';

const Space = () => <h1>hello from space</h1>;

export default Space;
```

And with this code I get this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

And this which I put here without knowing if it can help : `The above error occurred in the <LoadableComponent> component: react-dom.development.js:17117`

Yes i have the `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` installed and added in my babel config file.

Comment: I don't think you need the `.default` after your import statement `import('./Space')`. Also, you should try to use `React.lazy` instead of `react-loadable`. Why use an external library when React supports lazy loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I solved it by using React.lazy (see @Mario Subotic comment).

Here is my final code:

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const Test = lazy(() => import('./Space'));

const App = () => (
  <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
    <Test />
  </Suspense>
);
export default App;
```

> **Note**: apprently have to use `Suspense` around the component you're lazy loading.
>
> Source: https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/1810

Comment: Oh, React.lazy() must be wrapped with Suspense... thats important...